# Colemak not available as keyboard layout option on fresh 18.04 LTS install

Tags: keyboard-layout, 18.04

I would like to use the Colemak keyboard layout. In previous versions of Ubuntu (16, 17), it has been available as an input source. I just installed 18.04 LTS (into VMWare player) and Colemak is not available. I would have expected it to look exactly like [this blog post](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-keyboard-layout-for-native-languages/), which indicates it was there for at least one user. But I only have a handful of English sources and "Other", for which the only Colemak options are Filipino and Norwegian layouts!

I'm working around for now with `setxkbmap us -variant colemak`, but that doesn't persist across logins.

(For bonus points, how I would I also change the default keyboard layout for the login screen? Currently I need to type my password in QWERTY...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's available in *Settings -> Region & Language*. Click the + button, select *English (United States)*, and pick it from the sub menu.

If you are on a single user system, the input sources you add through the GUI should automatically (at next reboot) be made available also on the login screen.

Comment: I have two systems – on one, I can choose the input source in the login screen, on the other, I cannot.

Comment: @MPi: The difference can probably be seen if you check the contents of `/etc/default/keyboard` on the two systems.

Comment: I don't see colemak either.

Comment: After more searching, `setxkbmap us -variant colemak` worked for me. https://superuser.com/questions/227727/ubuntu-switch-keyboard-layout-to-colemak